# form data to csv no output

Tags: php, forms, export-to-csv

I'm new to php and trying to do a form whose inputs are appended to csv file but, Im not getting any output or errors........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<h3>Feedback Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name.." required>

    <label for="desg">Designation</label>
    <input type="text" id="desg" name="desg" placeholder="Your Designation" required>   

    <label for="rating">Rating</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="r1" value="excellent" checked> excellent<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="r2" value="good"> good<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id ="r3" value="needsimprovement" >needs improvement <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="r4" value="bad"> bad
<br/><br/>
    <label for="dept">Department</label>
    <input type="text" id="dept" name="dept" placeholder=" Dept" required>
    <label for="comments">Comments</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write comments here" style="height:200px" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn" >
  </form>
</div>
 <?php
 echo "datapage";

$nameErr = $emailErr = $desgErr = $ratingErr = "";
$name = $desg = $rating = $comment = $rating = "";



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = ($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["desg"])) {
    $emailErr = "desgn is required";
  } else {
    $desg = ($_POST["desg"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$desg)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["rating"])) {
    $rating = "";
  } else {
    $rating = ($_POST["rating"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$desg)) {
      $nameErr = "invalid";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = ($_POST["comment"]);
  }

   //$array = array($name,$desg,$rating,$comment);
   $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a+');
   $no_rows = count(file("data.csv"));
   $array1 = array(
        'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
        'name'  => $name,
        'desg'  => $desg,
        'rating' => $rating,
        'comments' => $comment
    );
   fputcsv($fp, $array1);
   fclose($fp);
   $error = '<label class="text-success">form submitted</label>';
}
/*function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
*/
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The least you could do is remove the unneeded parts of the code the (CSS, HTML HEAD etc). Also, an all-in-one santiize function is not a good idea mainly because you are applying functions without thinking, for example, you `trim` the data and then `stripslashes` but surely it should be the other way round? Not to mention that you are redundantly using `htmlspecialchars` Is your error reporting enabled? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: yes its enabled and no errors in log